# How do I burn an .img file onto a USB drive?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I'm using Windows and trying to burn this [Chromium OS nightly](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/vanilla.php) onto my USB drive.

Could someone recommend a program (freeware) that can "burn" an .img file onto a USB drive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "burn" ISO/img/cue+bin to USB drive](http://superuser.com/questions/55989/how-to-burn-iso-img-cuebin-to-usb-drive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Hexxeh's Chromium OS Flow instructions its recommended to use Image Writer which is here: https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer. Theres more info on it [here.](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/wiki/doku.php?id=windows_instructions)

Its not for exactly the same release, but the image file will most likely be the same format.

Comment: I get "Error 1: Incorrect function." when I try to use win32-image-writer on Windows 7 and can't write to the USB drive, even when I "Run as administrator". This happened for me on two different Windows 7 computers. It worked okay for me on Windows XP.

Comment: @ShannonWagner, on my computer this happens when I have any network drives mounted. For example Bitcasa and Wuala, both create virtual network drives to access their storage in the cloud. When I close those programs win32-image-writer starts without any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dd`](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) for that.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dd in the following way:

```
dd if=chromium.img of=/dev/sdb
```

Where /dev/sdb is the usb device, make sure to first unmount the usb device though.